# How to clear an image from RAM memory

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Every time I call the changeImage function the img image will change. The problem is that the RAM memory used by the app will increase every time the photo is changed, even if the previous photo is no longer on the screen.

```
enter code here import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var takenImage = UIImage()

    @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var buton: UIButton!

    var index = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func changeImage(_ sender: Any) {
        index+=1

        switch(index) {
          case 1:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i1")
          case 2:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i2")
          case 3:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i3")
          case 4:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i4")
          case 5:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i5")
          case 6:  img.image = UIImage(named: "i6")

          default: print("default");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to delete the old photos from the RAM memory

Comment: How is img defined? Can you show the code that calls the above function.

Comment: The code seen here looks OK. It should not be causing any sort of memory leak. The problem must lie somewhere else in your code. Also, how exactly are you measuring memory consumption?

Comment: irrelevant why not `img.image = UIImage(named: "i\(index)")`

Comment: @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UImage(named:)` caches the images (keeps them in memory to improve performance should you use them again). They won’t be removed from memory unless there is memory pressure.

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) says:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns the variant of that image that is best suited for the main screen. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or from an available asset catalog, and then returns the resulting object.
>
> The system may purge cached image data at any time to free up memory. Purging occurs only for images that are in the cache but are not currently being used.
>
> ...
>
> **Special Considerations**
>
> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using [`imageWithContentsOfFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init). This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Bottom line, if this is an image that you will repeatedly use in your app, you may choose to go ahead and use `UIImage(named:)`, confident that if there is memory pressure, the images will be released. But if this is not an image that you will use repeatedly, consider using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! And which is an alternative for UImage(named:) which doesn't keep them in memory?

Comment: [`UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init)

Comment: Keeping them in memory is not a problem. As soon as the system receives a low memory warning, it will clear the cached images.

Comment: @m_katsifarakis - If you really are likely to use the images again, I'd agree. But if they're images that you won't use again, you shouldn't use up memory unnecessarily. It will cause suspended apps to be jettisoned sooner than necessary, etc. We don't want to unnecessarily precipitate memory pressure scenarios unless there's some reason to do so.

Comment: @Rob I'm confused about the assets catalog. When you drag an image from the desktop to the assets catalog, is that all one needs to do to add an image to a project? Because in the file inspector tab, the full path of the image is its location in my computer (/Users/me/Desktop/...). When an app goes live on the App Store, what will that path become? Is there something that I need to do on my end or will it be handled automatically?

Comment: If using assets catalog, just use `UIImage(named:)` (or image literal) and it takes care of everything. If I had some large asset that I was going to use once and only once via `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`, then I probably wouldn’t put that in the assets catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Rob's answer,

Just one improvement on the redundant code, no need to use `switch-case` instead you can use,

```
@IBAction func changeImage(_ sender: Any) {
    index += 1
    img.image = UIImage(named: "i\(index)")
}
```